# Spring RMI Exception

Tags: java, spring, rmi

When I'm trying to make a big number of concurrency to call an RMI service, there is an exception happening.

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.net.ns.NetException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:227)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
```

But, everything is OK if the concurrency is small (less than 100).

I have went through the docs from SpringSource and found no related info. Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: did you find an answer to this question?